# Hubot Slack Attachments returns [object Object] in channel

Tags: bots, attachment, slack, hubot

I've hit a strange case, where the same code:

```
msg.reply( {"attachments": [ { "text": this is a test for attachments.", "color":"warning"} ] });
```

works when I am using a Direct Message with the bot, but when I am in a channel the bot returns `[object Object]`

Has anyone seen this before?

Thank you,
Andreea

Comment: msg.send works even on channels but msg.reply not working for me too.